# Error when attempting post hoc analyses on a binomial glm with interactions

Tags: glm, interaction, posthoc

Link to data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aMgwSPOZAEO3cICqLeQyqsDF_5WrhFXe

I am having a problem conducting post hoc analyses on a binomial glm using the data linked above.

Experiment: I am looking at the detectability (presence/absence) of an insect marker given 3 explanatory variables; application method (apptreat - factor, 2 levels), marker (factor, 2 levels), and exposure time (exp - numerical, 3 levels). Response variable (detect) is recorded as 1 for present and 0 for absent. After running the model several times to determine whether or not any interactions were significant, I came up with the following model.

Model:

```
id.glm2<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+apptreat*exp, family=binomial,     data=indiv_detec2)
anova(id.glm2, test="Chisq")
```

Output:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table
Model: binomial, link: logit
Response: detec
Terms added sequentially (first to last)


         Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                           906    1182.37              
apptreat      1  238.847       905     943.52 < 2.2e-16 ***
marker        1  156.844       904     786.68 < 2.2e-16 ***
exp           1  138.098       903     648.58 < 2.2e-16 ***
apptreat:exp  1    9.414       902     639.17  0.002153 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like to do a post hoc multiple comparison analysis to compare the differences within each variable including the interaction using the `glht` function in `multcomp` CRAN. I am able to get comparisons for the main effects with a warning about interactions being present (as expected from other posts). In order to perform posthoc analysis on the interaction I added a column to the data for the interaction using the following code and included it as a main effect in the glm model

```
indiv_detec2$AE<-interaction(indiv_detec2$apptreat, indiv_detec2$exp)
id.glm2<-glm(detec~apptreat+marker+exp+AE, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
anova(id.glm2, test="Chisq")
```

When I use the `glht` function to do the posthoc analysis on the interaction variable (AE) it results with the following error message

```
glht(m1, linfct = mcp(AE = "Tukey"))
```

> Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) : dimensions of coefficients and covariance matrix don't match

The data is unbalanced but I don't see how that would prevent the posthoc on the interaction variable and not the other variables. I know this problem has been brought up on other posts but I haven't been able to get the solutions mentioned in those posts to work. I'm assuming it's something I am doing wrong/simple mistake and just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You posted this question a year ago- did you ever find an answer to your problem? If so, you should post an answer to your own question and accept it.

There are a couple of things about what you've done that don't necessarily have to do with your question, but are relevant:

1) when you specify interactions in your model with "*", the model automatically includes the main effects without the interaction, i.e. you only needed to specify:

```
id.glm2<-glm(detec~apptreat*exp+marker, family=binomial, data=indiv_detec2)
```

whereas if you specify the interaction with ":" you need to include the main effects.

2) Your use of anova() appears incorrect, anova() is typically used to compared different models and your use of it above only specifies m1 (which I assume is the same model you built in your example, but with a different name) See the info page on anova(): [Description of anova usage](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/simsem/versions/0.5-14/topics/anova). I think you meant to use Anova() instead?

As for your use of the interaction function and your main issue, a little googling leads me to this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141792/how-to-compare-nested-factor-levels-to-mean-not-to-first-level-and-how-to-test) on cross validated, in which the same problem arises. In their code they note that NAs in their columns are causing the issue and need to be removed in order to make the code work. I would suggest you follow the instructions there by either manually removing them, or attempting to use na.rm=TRUE and see if that changes your result.